# Extjs - Multi level json for grid

Tags: json, extjs

I have a grid and i need/must (no matter y) to send a multilevel json to it.
example:

```
{ "root" : [ { 
        "affiliateId" : 8,
        "name" : "Affiliate Name",
        "email" : "affiliate@gmail.co.il",
        "manager" : { 
            "name"  : "I am the manager",
            "email" : "manager@gmail.co.il"
          },
      } ],
  "totalCount" : 1
}
```

now, when I build the grid fields I want to use the deeper items, for example:

```
{
        name:'manager_email',
        header: "Manager",
        dataIndex: 'manager.email',/******access a deep level******/
        width: 100,
        sortable: true,
        type:'text'
    }
```

I get no error, just empty cell in the grid.

Thanks

Comment: `manager.email` this is the deeper level. `manager` is an object, and `email` its the member, look at the json, it is as clear as it gets.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't understand what you meant. That was more of a joke (since you said "deeper") than a threat, anyway :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look into the `mapping` config option - define your field like this:

```
{
    name:'manager_email',
    header: 'Manager',
    mapping:'manager.email'
    ...
}
```

Another option might be to use a `renderer` this way:

```
{
    name:'manager_email',
    header: 'Manager',
    dataIndex: 'manager'
    renderer : function(value,metadata,record){
        return record.data.manager.email;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, instead of: record.data I used record.json.